# Can I view a history of my recent review audits?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I failed a review today and I was banned for a few days. I'm OK with it as I understand the reasoning.

But I don't understand the "You have made too many incorrect reviews..." since I think this one is the only one in the last week or so.

In the profile, I see tabs for `summary`, `answers`, `questions`, `tags`, `badges`, `favorites`, `bounties`, `reputation`, `activity`, `responses` and  `vote`. But no `audit` or `review`.

Where can I see my review history?

Related: should there be an review-history or audit-history tag (similar to flag-history and revision-history)? I'm having trouble locating similar questions.

Comment: If you have only failed one audit, it is possible a moderator banned you manually. How obvious was this audit that you failed...?

Comment: @CodyGray If this is going to turn into a review-audit-specific question, can we also have the question statement reflect that? I still see "Where can I see my review history?"

Comment: Related: [How many review audits did I fail?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192899), [How to access history of review audits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185359), [How many failed audits trigger a review suspension?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/195099)

Comment: Thanks @Cody - "How obvious was this audit that you failed...?"... looking back, I think it was pretty obvious. I fixated on a change to some byte codes, and missed the obvious.

Comment: Uhh, I'm not seeing the difference @Dennis. The question is basically why am I banned when I thought I only failed one audit—is there any way to confirm that? Feel free to modify the title if you think I've got it wrong, though.

Comment: @CodyGray It's just that now we have "Can I view a review history of my recent review audits" as the title and "Where can I see my review history?" in the question body. Figured we may as well change the latter too.

Comment: From Shog9 at [How to access history of review audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185359/how-to-access-history-of-review-audits): "... including some rather useless formatting changes." - I'm guilty of this. I despise "cell phone speak", and I will approve the grammatical corrections of "i -> I", "u -> you", etc.

Comment: @jww So do/will I. And I encourage you to keep doing so. That isn't what Shog means. He's talking about the curious phenomenon where people will edit posts to add inline code formatting to random words/phrases that are not code. Occasionally you also see superfluous use of bold text. Do note [the](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2271561) two [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2271554) he links.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192899/how-many-review-audits-did-i-fail

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Review History is in the "activity" tab. Click on it and you'll get the following options:

- all
- accepts
- posts
- badges
- comments
- revisions
- **reviews**
- suggestions

Snippet from a screenshot for convenience:

[image]

---

However, given that you're interested in the audits in particular, we'll have to dig deeper. As @animuson points out in a [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185359/how-to-access-history-of-review-audits#comment567679_185360) on a different question

> Only review audits that you pass get listed in your activity history. Failed audits are never listed there. If you're still under 10,000 reputation, they do get listed in the history tab for that specific queue (if over 10k you'd probably never find them). I should also note that review audits are only identified as such when viewing the actual review item screen. They are not labeled as "Review Audit Passed/Failed" in the lists. –  animuson Jun 21 '13 at 17:31

You're still until 10k rep for now, so sounds like from this comment you can still look at the review history for that queue (For example, the Suggested Edits history is at https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/history). Barring that, I'm not sure if they're accessible at all (poking around Stack Exchange Data Explorer turned up nothing)

Comment: Thanks @Dennis. I found it. But it appears it lacks audits and their results. The audit appears to be missing even under the "all" tab.

Comment: @jww I'll pop into the Data Explorer and see if I can pull up the audits from there.

Comment: Thanks @Dennis. Don't expend too much energy on it. It was more a curiosity thing for me (I'm getting older, and my memory is not what it used to be). Two days won't break me.

Comment: @jww Nah, it's fine. May as well neaten up this one and make it a good answer for review audits. I'm already pretty far into it anyway

Comment: They are in your browser history. This is how I've been able to review every audit question I've ever seen, including failed audits.

Comment: Note that nowadays users with >10k can now filter for their own review history, so that doesn't matter any more.

Comment: There is a *my review history* link on the review queue history tab that lets 10k+ users filter the history to their own reviews only.