# Why can't we see our failed review audits to learn from?

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-audits

Today I got a 2 day review ban for having a disagreement with the review audits over a question. Not a big deal, but I couldn't remember the last time I failed an audit, and I was wondering "is there maybe a pattern? Am I maybe wrong and we really want copy pasted code-only-answers from other questions answers on closed-as-duplicate questions?"

So I was looking around and found [mentions of that you can not see your failed audits in the review history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260962/can-i-view-a-history-of-my-recent-review-audits/).

So may I ask: why that? I think this is a good opportunity to learn, to have an overview over your failed review audits and maybe also how "bad" the disagreement was, so you can see where you and the community differ. Why can't we see them? Is this some securit-by-obscurity thing so that we can't learn more about to detect what could possibly be an audit?

Comment: [related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192899/how-many-review-audits-did-i-fail)

Comment: On this note, I'd also like to be to see why I failed an audit. At the moment I have no other option than to click "I understand" - when I don't. Perhaps showing the close reason that was used with a failed audit could be good.

Comment: If this happens to be "fixed", I would like to see it private. Some people would prefer not to get their history revealed because of feeling ashamed or another reason.

Comment: If you're going to be ashamed of how you review, don't review at all. The roboreviewers *should* feel ashamed. Of course, if any of them had any sense of shame whatsoever they'd stop badge whoring and go away.

Comment: Would also be nice to have to have a kind of _dispute_ button. If you fail, you can only click _I understand_, but you don't necessarily always understand

Comment: @neelsg What would that button actually do?

Comment: @svick flag an audit question for review.  Seems like a good idea, as I have definitely failed audits that I didn't agree with.

Comment: @svick, not sure exactly, but maybe: Link to a meta question discussing why this post should be reviewed the way it is? You could then weigh in with your opinion on it and really understand the why others feel differently. I have had to manually ask about one audit in meta before, but only after I clicked "I understand" which just felt wrong.

Comment: Keep in mind that the audit reviews aren't always right. They are chosen by an algorithm and not by humans. It may not be that you don't understand, it may be that you made the right decision and audit review is wrong. One thing I've done in the past with a failed audit review on a valid answer was to go to the answer and write a comment as to why the answer was perfectly valid and not at all a good example of a bad answer. What was curious in that case was that the answer had positive votes (to which I added my own) and was an accepted answer. The system is most definitely not perfect.

Comment: Just one note on my comment above: I was able to hit the 'back' button on my broswer and get back to the failed audit question that way.

Comment: Actually you can view fails for `Low Quality Posts` and `Suggested Edits`(but unfortunately not during ban). Go to review, choose Review type, open `History tab` and click on `Review` link to the right from question(but unfortunately only one at a time). And you will see result of this review.

Comment: @Uriil, Maybe this isn't the case with the First Posts queue. I couldn't find any of the failed reviews. I know for certain that two of my first four reviews ever were failed audits, but all I saw were the reviews that went through normally. Word of caution: I innocently followed Uriil's suggestion and hit the 'Next' button thinking I would be taken to my next historical review. Instead I found myself doing actual reviews!!!

Comment: @FinalContest FYI your review history is already public by design to 10K+ users: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2682142/final-contest?tab=activity&sort=reviews

Comment: I guess the obvious question is, why restrict this at all? I'd have a zero rep design for reviewing failed audits.

Comment: @Uriil: You mean http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/history ? you can look there even during a ban, that doesn't make finding past failed audits in any more accessible, and I think in the case of audits for already deleted posts, this won't work, or at least you won't be able to see the post (unless maybe you are 10k, dunno)

Comment: So much this...
I just got a 7-day review ban for what appears to be my first failed audit since the 2-day one, a couple of weeks, maybe even a month ago. Funny enough both failed audits were in the low quality queue.
I'd like to see what other audits I failed, so I can at least learn from it -.- I don't think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24241514/revisions) should've been deleted as "spam", for example, since it's a good answer that also links to a free tool that can do something similar. If that's the only failed audit since the 2-day ban, I'll stay out of the "low quality" queue...

Comment: The frustrating thing is that I'm 10 reviews (1 day) away from 1k on the suggested edits queue :-/ ... Maybe I got careless, but I'd like to see if that was the case.

Comment: @Cerbrus: Looks like you have a disagreement with the community here then ;)

Comment: It was deleted by a moderator, not necessarily the result of a flag. I can see why it was flagged as spam, but I feel it's kinda borderline. Oh, [link to the audit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5300516)

Comment: I think this would be a great thing to do. Having feedback on anything we did is always helpful.

Comment: @M.A.Kishawy: From another meta question I came to the conclusion that we are not supposed to learn, but we are supposed to either fit already perfectly into what audits try to check, or we should stop auditing (and close voting etc.) alltogether. After all, there are so many people on SO, just sieving out the bad ones vs. spending effort into teaching them makes little difference in the end.

Answer (score 6):

This was a bug, which Oded fixed in the context of [a larger feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228955/allow-all-reviewers-to-see-deleted-posts-they-reviewed):

> as of this morning, all posts reviewed will remain visible to their reviewers in the context of the relevant review task. "Skip" does not count as a review for this purpose (or most other purposes).

Comment: Yay, took only 6-8 uhm... whatever... also the way this question got closed as duplicate of a much newer one is intresting in that context...