# Failed review audit - see your own record - is the ban justifiable?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-audits, link-only-answers, review-suspension

I just failed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/5654936) review audit.

Usually I flag link-only answers as "not an answer" which would've been correct. I didn't do this here, since the link is to the official manual, not some tutorial of someone where you can't be sure if it's right, what he writes. And the link isn't broken.

How is your opinion on links to official manuals?

I like reviewing and I actually think that my record isn't so bad, that the penalty is adequate. Please reconsider my ban from reviewing.

Also it would be nice to actually see your own record, when you have failed a review. I'd guess, that without seeing the record, most people question the penalty, might get angry, stop reviewing...
Whereas when you see, that there are more failed reviews than you can remember, you might even agree that you really deserve to be banned to reconsider reviewing behavior.

Comment: SO convention is that answers should actually contain an answer, not just a link to an answer - regardless of whether the target is official documentation or some random blog. Quoting the relevant piece and linking for additional information can be OK. Keep in mind even official sites re-organize and break links all the time.

Comment: part of the question related to learning from audit failures is addressed in [Why can't we see our failed review audits to learn from?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261990/why-cant-we-see-our-failed-review-audits-to-learn-from)

Comment: The stackoverflow review audits are an automated joke. I just got failed for a second time - the 'excuse' being the answer is "not an answer". Bulls***. It's short but it is precisely an answer. Yet I'm now blocked for 7 days despite having around 90-95% approved results, most of the rejected being in the early days. The net result of this garbage yet again is fine, don't want me to review? I won't. Have fun with your backlog.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I'd guess, that without seeing the record, most people question the penalty, might get angry, stop reviewing...

Then they'd do the exact same thing if they *could* see the record.

When you're banned from review, it's because of the audit listed in the message you're given. Your past history *influences* this, but you can't "earn" any number of audit-failures by virtue of audit passes (or other reasonable reviews).

You're given a break because you overlooked a problem - the purpose is to give you a chance to avoid missing similar problems in the future, and if you don't feel that's important then... Not coming back is OK.

Next time you see an answer like that, consider editing it to add a *brief* summary of what's being linked to. The link may work now, but if it doesn't work tomorrow then that wouldn't be the first time Sun/Oracle have broken documentation links - best to be proactive rather than waiting until you need to depend on Archive.org to get the answer.

Comment: `Next time you see an answer like that, consider editing it to add a brief summary of what's being linked to.` Be aware though, you need to edit outside the review session rather than clicking the "EDIT" button in the review page. Clicking EDIT is considered a supportive decision, and you can be banned if the review task is an audit.