# Where did the review audit go?

Tags: bug, review-audits, deleted-answers

I failed my first review audit in a while now, and I thought I'd go back and see what I should have reacted to about the post, but it seems to be gone. The answer was answered on a deleted question, so that's probably why it's not showing up anymore, but that's pretty dumb, because the whole point of audits is to slow you down and think about what you did wrong before moving on to the next review:

> Don't worry, we've already handled this post appropriately – but please *take a minute to look it over closely*, keeping in mind the guidance above.

The review referred to is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/7701378).

To me, this seems like a bug, and can quite easily be fixed, so I'll tag it as a bug.

This question is essentially the same as [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261990), but it doesn't have any answers and no progress and/or change in over a year, so this question should stay open.

Comment: I'm guessing the reason you can't see the post is because it's already deleted, and you don't have 10k to see deleted posts. I'm not saying it should stay like that, but that is the most likely reason.

Comment: @gunr2171 Yep, that's what I thought. Seeing as most audits most likely are deleted posts, that's quite dumb, it's quite hard learning from your mistakes when you can't review what you reviewed wrong (heh).