# Is it intentional that 'Reject and Edit' option doesn't work in Suggested Edits review audits?

Tags: support, bug, edits, review-audits, rejected-edits

When doing some [suggested edits reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits), I came across a suggestion that needed editing, but it was an audit to see if I was paying attention. Right after pressing the "Reject and Edit" button, it just said that I passed the test and went to the next suggested edit but I actually wanted to edit that post.

Is this a bug or an intended feature? If it's a feature, then why?

Comment: It would be a waste of the reviewers time to allow them to edit an audit, because it's useless.

Comment: It moves on because the post has already been handled, though it's extremely frustrating when there's a post that needs editing, but clicking "edit" triggers an audit failure. [The best move is to not play](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts#review-queue-helper)

Comment: If you want to edit that post you can go into your [history](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/history).

Comment: Edit review audits tend to be faked, done by the machine inserting random words into a post.  That clearly happened with [your audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27229103), fixing it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @HansPassant the fix would not be related to fake edit. The post (not the one that you mentioned) had some other problems with the formatting before it was inserted with random words.

Comment: @WaiHaLee, thanks for the tips. But the button is still deceptive though, I thought there would be an editor opened for me when I click the edit button but there wasn't.

Comment: I guess, then, that you could reframe your question as a feature request - something like "'Reject and Edit' for review audits should pass the audit and allow editing the original post".

Comment: It's usually not logical to actually edit those audit posts... Sore, it's slightly misleading, but changing the button for audits would make the audit even more obvious.

Comment: @Zoe Apparently Reject & Edit passes the audit, it just doesn't give you the option to also edit the post.

Comment: Maybe if you pass an audit by clicking Reject and Edit, you can get an "edit it anyway" button?

Answer (score 1):

The behavior looks intentional as generally review audits are automatically generated bogus changes to otherwise normal posts. While indeed there are rare cases when edit to such post would be needed in the most cases such posts are  good enough on they own and building another mode for "reject" audit likely was considered unnecessary.

If you really feel the need to edit that post you can get it from the queue's review history explained in [Why can't we see our failed review audits to learn from?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261990/why-cant-we-see-our-failed-review-audits-to-learn-from) and linked big meta post (the link for the particular queue - https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/history).

---

For the particular [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63828725/i-just-added-a-new-area-to-my-code-however-it-wont-let-me-click-on-any-of-them) that triggered this post the right action is not "edit" but "close as typo" - while retyping image to text is a noble action it is neither recommended nor actually going to significantly improve the  post which is roughly "I created text resembling HTML with half of the tags open/mismatched and it did not render".