# Can we make it easier to see our audit history?

Tags: feature-request, review-audits

Currently, to find a previously reviewed audit, you have to either sift through the "reviews" sub-tab (under the "activity" tab on your profile), or, go to your reviewing history of the queue that you passed/failed the audit in. Which in both cases can take some time to do, even if you don't have a huge reviewing history (since you have to check *every* link to see if it's an audit).

So, could we have a new sub-tab under our "activity" tab that displays *only* passed and failed audits (from all queues), and maybe displays our fail/pass rate as well?

Maybe something like this?

> [image]

---

<sup>Note, I'm aware that this post is *similar* to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260962/2246344) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185359/227577) post, but they were asking *how* to view audit history, whereas I'm proposing a feture request to do so, therefore this isn't a dupe.</sup>

Comment: @Payeli Fair point; still, it's good to review one's audit history every now and then (even if not banned), to better see which type of audits you're failing more often (so you can learn more easily from your mistakes). And having a percentage of passed audits is generally quite interesting too.

Comment: fingers crossed for such feature implementation.

Answer (score 6):

I know this post is two years old, but I just got banned for the first time from reviewing, and it's the first time in a while that I recall failing an audit... yeah, I am not about to click through every single review I've done in the past month to try and guess why.

I agree that this would be an extremely helpful feature to have, but I don't think we need a new tab just for audits. A simple and effective change could be to append "failed/passed audit" somewhere in the normal review history display. The context would be helpful, too - for instance, I've read elsewhere on meta that reviewing too fast causes the system/mods to be more suspicious.

Here's a mockup of what I'm envisioning:

[image: review history page with added audit text]

Comment: Well mods have nothing to do with audits which are part of a fully automatic system. I always wonder what you hope to learn by having all audits listed. It will just be a list of pride or shame, so to speak. The whole idea of audits is that they trigger you to be more careful, perhaps give you a little vacation to think it over, and then we all forget it ever happened. So why specifically want a feature that makes the audits basically be on your radar forever?

Comment: @Gimby I only mentioned mods because I saw some posts where a mod had banned a user from reviewing based on some query they ran which took user history into account, maybe this is outdated now. I'm mainly interested in this because 1) this would let me check myself to see that I'm doing ok, or easily find failed audits to see what I am doing wrong 2) curiosity, this is data that is available, but not easily accessible. I don't think it'd be bad to be thinking about audits more, if it makes you more careful when reviewing.

Comment: So now that you've had several "STOP!" messages flung at your head and you've had to endure the shock of a review ban, you're going to forget about them again? I hope not ;) Regardless, I think having a list like this makes it easier to ask about it on meta - which everyone who repeatedly fails audits should be doing, it's a clear sign that guidance is needed. On that basis your suggestion gets my vote.

Answer (score 1):

I have just been redirected to this post after requesting such feature. I like reviewing as it's another way to contribute to the community. As I learned a lot on Stack Overflow I'd like to improve it. I have a feeling that correct reviews actually do improve it, however wrong reviews can cause harm. I would really like to have a possibility to easily review my reviews. First of all it would be perfect to know the percentage of audits passed/failed and then how many of reviews in each queue were consistent with the final decision.