# Reviews audited failed

Tags: support, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

Getting below message after reviewed correctly. *(Except ONE mistake)*

[image]

I was reviewing some `Low Quality Post`. Around `12-15` Posts I have audited correctly but one of them was was incorrect.

I want to know, *How can we `Highlight` our mistake?* Where can we see the `Full Details` - *What you did wrong?* Below image is showing me only my action. ***Not the comments.(That you did wrong)***

[image]

See below image what I've reviewed and others also reviewed the same with same action.

**Note:** I have just shared only one post that has been reviewed by all SO moderator with the same action. There are few others but I am not posting here.

[image]

*In short,* Can anyone please tell where can I find my all mistakes? ***(This is my real question)***

Comment: How did that not scream **SPAM** at you - what made you say that it "Looks OK"?

Comment: Clicking on a link in a picture does not work: http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10737163 . Still can't see it since the answer is deleted though :/

Comment: @Gimby here you go; http://i.stack.imgur.com/60bkW.png

Comment: That was only my mistake, but what about others that were correctly reviewed. I pressed on Looks OK and I am accepting it. But where can I find my others mistake.

Comment: @rajeshpanchal Then that 'Don't know how this audit is valid?' bit that is currently there at the very top of your question is quite misleading.

Comment: Related feature request: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263113/can-we-make-it-easier-to-see-our-audit-history

Comment: I don't believe it's possible for you to review your own failed audit history - but that's because we'd like reviewers to ask (if needs be) and understand the reason they failed an audit at the time - not dwell about past mistakes. With pretty much all failed audits it's possible to look again at the audit (by following the link in the message) *more carefully* and it should be obvious the reason as to why you failed. Your previous audit failure was random gibberish into the post which you also said "Looks OK" to. Again, the reason why will be obvious if you look at it again *carefully*.

Answer (score 11):

I'm really sorry but if you really clicked Looks OK because you feel that answer is OK then your 7 days ban should give you enough time to better understand what spam looks like.

Even if it isn't spam there isn't really the slightest attempt to answer the question. This answer is not helpful, is not the quality we want on Stack Overflow. The audit is perfect and by failing it you proved that you need a time-out.

[image: spam answer review audit failed]

If you want to review how you're doing you might try my script I created for [Adding the consensus to review's history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251508/158100)

Comment: Isn't this answer helpful for future visitors that run into the same issue?

Comment: I think none will search for such kind of issue ;) I'm feeling sad :( Because of my bad question. :'(

Comment: Sure, but I spend time providing an answer for the last part of your question. That is still valuable I think because users have no possibility to do that easily and my script somewhat helps in that.