# Where do we draw the line for link-only posts?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits, link-only-answers

I recently got review-banned for failing [a review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/7941145). I don't much care that I'm banned<sup>1</sup>; I'll wait two days, maybe devote some time to actually answering, and keep reviewing.

This is the text, in case anyone can't see it:

> Install SCVMM on TFS server and then go to TFS admin console and configure Lab management then you will able to add Machines in Environment.
>
> visit : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee943322.aspx

Now, as far as I can tell, this was deleted because it's a link-only answer. That's the impression I get from the comment, at least. Is it, though? I'm not saying that it's a *good* answer, but it does provide information beyond what the link has: That whole first sentence is an answer, albeit a badly-punctuated one. If you pretend the link is dead, it's still at least an answer, though a bad one.

So why was it deleted for being link-only?

*(If it was actually deleted for some other reason, this entire question is based on a flawed premise, so I recommend we close as 'not reproducible')*

<sup>1: Especially since I actually *did* fudge that review; I should have skipped, downvoted or edited, not said 'no action needed'. Oh well. Lesson learned. It bugs me that (as far as I remember, since [we can't see our failed audits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260963/1863564)) I've only failed three in the past month and I *still* got banned, but whatever.</sup>

Comment: The question is "How can I diagnose this problem?"; the answer answers "How do I solve this problem", so, it wasn't deleted for being "link only" but for not answering the question at all.

Comment: @Braiam I seem to remember that incorrect and irrelevant answers aren't meant to be deleted, though, just downvoted. I can't find the right question to cite, however. I'll see if I can find it tomorrow.

Comment: @Braiam: There's a comment on the answer saying "While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes." That implies that it was deleted for being link-only.

Comment: @abarnert and? that doesn't mean that all reviewers agree with that comment. I wouldn't deleted it using that reason, but the one I exposed. The reasons why answers are deleted are many, and the most plausible one is the one I gave. The fact that there's a comment saying that it's a "link-only" answer doesn't mean that that was the sole or even any of the reasons why it was deleted.

Comment: @Braiam: Sure, the comment only means _one_ person thought it should be deleted for being link-only, and we don't know if anyone actually voted on that basis. But if that's the only information we have, it implies that there's a good chance it's one of the reasons. Just like when a question or answer is downvoted, and there's a comment explaining what's wrong with it, we don't actually _know_ that comment had anything to do with anyone's reasons for downvoting, but it's usually a good guess.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Re: not being able to see your failed audits... actually, _you can_, but they're not particularly useful. On the Review page, click `recent reviews` of the review queue to view, then in the top-right corner click on the History tab. Your audit reviews will be in there somewhere, but as most audits tend to have been deleted then unless you have access to moderator tools (10k+ rep) you won't be able to see the post.

Comment: You just can't judge whether such an answer is useful from the review page.   If it is the *only* answer then it has merit, at least if gives the OP and other visitors something to look at.  If it is not and a better answer is posted then it doesn't have a much of a reason to live.  I *always* open the Q in another tab to have a look-see.  And never once failed this kind of audit, it is always obvious that it is a deleted post :)

Comment: @abarnert: Auto-comments from LQP, *especially* in audits, are ***filthy rotten misleading lies***. They can never be trusted to let you know why the answer should be or have been deleted.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: I realize you have to use your judgment and not blindly trust the auto-comments. But really, when 33% of an answer is the link, and someone used the link-only auto-comment, I think it's a pretty good guess that some people really did believe it was a link-only answer. In fact, I think it's a _better_ guess than to assume that everyone who voted to delete actually thought it through to the same depth as you and realized there was a better reason to delete this question.

Comment: @abarnert: Well, yes. Certainly someone did think it was link-only. There's no guarantee that it was, or that it was deleted for that reason (justified or no).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- What's more important is to have an answer here and not expect the answer to be found via separate link.
- The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19223879/microsoft-test-manager-cannot-install-test-agent-on-these-machines-when-creati) is "*How can I diagnose this problem?*" While the deleted answer was a one-liner and points to a link to find the steps to diagnose. It would have been much better if the steps to diagnose were actually posted in the answer itself. It is very much fine to add a credit saying "*As suggested in this following site, follow these steps*".

**Such links could be found by a Google search too, then why to participate in Stack Overflow?** People look for a complete answer here, and not half-answers or link-only answers. I completely agree with the comment:

> while this link may answer the question, it is better to include the
>   essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.
>   Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: But the point is that the answer does actually include the essential parts. If you follow the rule of "would this answer be as helpful to someone even if the link were dead?", I think it might be. (I am partly just guessing, since this is way out of my area of expertise…) It's of only limited usefulness with the link, and of nearly the same limited usefulness without. If so, downvoting but not deleting (or deleting for a different reason) seems the right thing to do.

Comment: Also, does the link actually provide the steps to diagnose the problem? When I click it, I get an "Unable to Service Request" response from MSDN; trying to search for a live or cached equivalent page, I think it's just a page telling you how to get to and use the Lab Management thingy on the console, which is no more than what the answer itself includes.

Comment: @abarnert Technically, the question is about MTM, i.e. Microsoft Test Manager, and the upvoted answer talks about it. While, the deleted answer is about something not directly relevant and then it is supported by a link. I think this is the strongest reason that it was flagged. I was not the one who flagged it to delete though, however, I guess this is what the reason might have been.

Comment: Sure, and I agree the answer is a bad answer. But if it's just as good (i.e., not very) without the link as with it, it's not a link-only answer.

Comment: I'm clarifying the question to add that this is actually a pretty bad example of what I'm talking about and to take the answer on its own, assuming that it's relevant to the question at hand. Thanks for the great answer, however. I'm just confused about one thing: _Does this count as a link-only answer_? I'm well aware it's a _bad_ answer, but is it _link-only_? It has some (albeit little) value without the link, so should it be downvoted or deleted?

Comment: Yes, it has a value, however very little to be posted as an answer per Stack Overflow standards. I wish the most essential parts would have been posted, and it would be even better if it were made as bullet points. And that the reference could have been that link.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know enough about the question to be sure, but it seems to me like you were right. Or at least like it's a borderline case, and you were arguably right.

From what I can tell, the answer is of limited usefulness at best, even with the link. Mainly because it just offers a solution that may or may not turn out to be the right solution after the problem has been diagnosed, rather than answering the question of how to diagnose the problem, or even providing enough background for the questioner to figure out if this will be the right solution.

And without the link, that doesn't change. It's still of limited usefulness at best; it still solves the problem if this turns out to be the problem and does nothing if it doesn't, and does nothing to help the questioner figure out if it will be the right solution.

So, downvoting the answer, or deleting it for a different reason, seems appropriate. Deleting it for being link-only… I'm not so sure.