# Failed review audit because of inconsistent tag description

Tags: support, review-queues, disputed-review-audits

I just encountered this while reviewing posted questions:

1. The question had to do with **future**,
2. The description shown upon hovering on the tag stated that questions about **future** are off topic on Stack Overflow,
3. Based on that, I flagged the question as off topic.

It then turned out that it was a sort of exam question and my action was "reprimanded" because the question *was* properly phrased.

It may be a good idea to maintain consistency across this fantastic site.

Comment: It's probably a review audit; can you post a link please? Sometimes bad questions are chosen as audits, sometimes not, but then we can explain why.

Comment: Yes, it was an audit (verifying I'm not asleep I guess). Link: I don't really know how to recover it or search for the specific question (since it was an AUDIT question and not a real one).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/review - you'll see a link to the failed audit there. Unless you're not yet banned, of course. Then you might find the audit in your browser history. Or a moderator might be able to see which audit you failed.

Comment: Note, don't see any such link (perhaps I'm missing it).

Comment: I don't see any failed audits on your [review tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4991677/fdavidov?tab=activity&sort=reviews) either. Are you sure you failed it? Did you see the **STOP** message?

Comment: Yes, there was a STOP. Browsing history would not help since SO is in my favorites. Just to make things clear, I'm not offended or anything even close to that. I just found something that appears to be an inconsistency and reported it. You may check what the tooltip for **future** is and perhaps rephrase it.

Comment: Well, the fact that [future] should not be used, doesn't mean it's an off-topic question. Another way to find review audits is via this page: http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/history (assuming you were reviewing first posts) - it should be in the list.

Comment: The tag wiki excerpt says that questions _about future events_ are off-topic. But "future" is also a concept in concurrent programming, and questions involving this concept are very much on-topic.

Comment: Gents (and/or ladies): (1) Since it was an AUDIT it perhaps is not logged in the review history (don't see it there); (2) Yes, if was while reviewing first posts; (3) I know what I read in the pop for **future** and it clearly stated what I mentioned. As for @S.L.Barth last post (with the phrasing) the question was about the meaning of the word in programming. I think that we all spent already too much time on this. I appreciate (and highly value!!!) your response and interest, and suggest we keep things in proportion. Thank you.

Comment: We're not reprimanding you; apologies if that is how my comment came across. Meanwhile, audits should be visible in a user's review history.

Comment: @Glorfindel Failed audits are not posted to the user profile review tab

Comment: @FDavidov Do you remember what queue you were in when you failed the audit?

Comment: @NathanOliver OK, didn't know that. Passed audits do, and I can't remember my last failed audit so I couldn't check.

Comment: I believe some audits are auto-generated from valid questions by applying completely invalid edits - it could be one of those cases with tag added (also all cases I've seen are just clearly nonsense edits).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov but that's Suggested Edits. First of all, flagging posts is not the point of Suggested Edits; second, the asker isn't 2K yet.

Comment: @StephenLeppik Maybe other queues use same for audits? I don't know - that was my guess why tag could be present on valid question. (There really no need for generated bad questions so :) )

Comment: @NathanOliver Audits in some queues go in your profile, and in some queues they don't.  I forget which ones are which.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Suggested edit audits don't change tags.

Comment: @Servy Only passed audits.  Failed audits are only shown in the history tab in the review queue.

Comment: @NathanOliver I occasionally go to user's profiles to look up audits they've failed, and I find them often enough.  I know that certain queues don't include them, but some do include failed audits.

Comment: @Servy Really?  [This](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260963/4342498) states they are never shown.  I wonder if that has changed.  If it has we need to update that answer.

Comment: @NathanOliver It's possible that I'm remembering an older behavior, or simply that the post in question was related to a particular queue, and not all queues.  I'm not 100%, but I'm pretty sure that they're not never shown.

Comment: @Servy You can find them [here](http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/history) but AFAIK not from the user profile directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've encountered a bad audit. Probably. It's impossible to tell without a link.

> ### Why was an obviously bad post chosen for me to review positively?
>
> Review audits are chosen automatically. The system isn't perfect, meaning that every so often a poor quality post slips through and is upvoted, which the system interprets as a "high-quality" post.
>
> If you encounter one of these: You can post it on the child meta tagged [support](/questions/tagged/support)[disputed-review-audits](/questions/tagged/disputed-review-audits) to draw attention to it, containing a link to either the audit task or the post, and why you disagree with the audit. ♦ moderators can remove the audit from your history, and other users can downvote, vote to close, and counteract the decisions that lead to it being chosen as high-quality.

It's important to emphasize 2 things:

1. One *single* failed audit does not get you review-banned. Failing a large number of them does.
2. Since it was an audit, the post was **never actually flagged.** You need to click the link to the post and flag it *there.*

Comment: SO is a FANTASTIC (!!!!!) site as a service, and one of the best examples I saw for its outstanding response, valuable features, robustness and clarity. Most of all, **I highly appreciate the absence of useless pyrotechnical junk**. So don't worry, this little glitch did nothing to my perception of this site. I thank you for taking the time to giving a complete answer.

Comment: Just did it :-)).

Comment: The fact that a question contains the tag "future" doesn't mean it's a bad question.  It's *entirely* likely that it's a perfectly acceptable question that's not at all off topic.  Just assuming that every audit everyone fails must be a bad audit is extremely harmful behavior, as it means when people (as is most often the case) actually make a mistake, they don't learn from it and correct their behavior.

Comment: @Servy  you might be right—but it's impossible to tell without a link.

Comment: @StephenLeppik And yet you choose to specifically assert that it's a bad audit anyway, even though there's considerable evidence to indicate that it was a good audit and no evidence at all to indicate that it wasn't.

Answer (score 2):

You are correctly stopped from wrong flagging.

Invalid tag by itself does not in any way make question off-topic - so if you flag posts "off-topic" solely based on invalid tag than audit correctly warning against wrong behavior.

Correct action in such case could be to "edit" to remove/replace unrelated tag (assuming content of the post is reasonable, otherwise act on content).

There is always "skip" if you are not 100% sure that action is correct.